# How can our country be our "principle of being"? (St. Thomas Aquinas)

Tags: aquinas, medieval, natural-law

[*Summa Theologica* II-II q. 101 a. 1](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS101.html#SSQ101A1THEP1):

> In the second place, the principles of our being and government (*nostri esse et gubernationis principium*) are our parents and our country (*patria*), that have given us birth and nourishment.

But I don't understand how a country can be our principle of being. [Freddoso's translation of the *Summa Theologiæ*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7724) seems to explain Thomas' argument better:

> But in second place, the principles of our being and governance are our parents and our country, by whom and in which we are born and governed.

But I still don't understand how simply being born somewhere makes that place one of the principles of our being.

Comment: The idea of a country as a mere place of birth is rather modern. During middle ages, people did not move around much, and travel to foreign lands was fraught with peril. Even staying in place was dangerous without the protection of the landlord or the town, and their soldiers. So the survival and livelihood, law and order, were owed, in large part, to the community one was born into, and the broader feudal system it was embedded into, the "country". Aquinas analogizes and embeds this mundane hierarchy into the one grander still, with the God on top, the first principle of our being.

Comment: Maybe "principle" is not only efficient cause but also "reason why" and thus we may consider that humans are social beings..

Answer (score 1):

[*Patria*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=la&l=Patria#Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=patrius1-contents) (from *pater* = "father") means more than a geographical area; it means "fatherland" (which includes land, culture, language, religion, politics, race, etc.). Just as a father is the principle of generation of his child, so too is the *patria*.

Similarly, [*Sentencia De anima* lib. 3 l. 4 n. 5](https://isidore.co/aquinas/DeAnima.htm#34) [619]:

> [Homer] calls the sun the “father of men” because of the part it plays in human procreation; for man is born from man and the sun [*Homo enim generat hominem et sol.*].

<sup>Aristotle quotes this Homeric maxim, too.</sup>

The *patria* an [instrumental cause](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34251) of procreation. The *patria*'s

- land provides food so the father can eat and create semen: "the seed (*semen*) is from the surplus of food" ([*Summa suppl.* q. 80 a. 4](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/XP/XP080.html#XPQ80A4THEP1) ad 4)
  <sub>Food production ultimately depends on the sun; cf. Homer's maxim quoted above.</sub>
- political society provides for his and his children's social, educational, and bodily needs; the family is an imperfect society, one "which does not contain within itself all the means necessary to achieve its end." ([*Integralism*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7822) ch. 1)
- etc.

Comment: What exactly is the role of the patria in human procreation?

Comment: @GuilhermedeSouza See what I added.

Answer (score 1):

Parents form a community ( the human couple) , but every community ( according to Aristotle)  is a part of the only self-sufficient community, the City.  And every part of the City is to the City what a part of the living body is to the whole body. Holistic conception of society and community.

Hence, if one owes his being (  and his conservation) to his parents, he ( so to say, transitively) owes his being to his political community.

Socrates claims in this sense that he has a debt and a duty towards Athens.

Without the social system in which they were immerged, how could my parents have provided me health care, physical security, instruction, etc. ?